# Does iOS Firebase framework downloads the file on different queue?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, firebase-storage

I have an app where I send a request to Firebase to download file from it's database.

Here is the code snippet!

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to download
let islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg")
// Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
islandRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
    // ... imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
  }
}
```

So does Firebase sends the downloading operation in other queue other than MAIN queue? The reason why I have question is because I want to update my imageView.image so it would appear on the screen. I do know iOS framework requires MAIN queue to update the UI, so I want to make sure if I need to update it on main queue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Storage does the download on a separate background queue so as to not block UI, but surfaces the callback on the main queue, which allows you to perform UI work immediately.

If you want to change which queue the callback is surfaced on, you can use the `FIRStorage.setCallbackQueue()` method ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasestorage/interface_f_i_r_storage.html#a96538feb8fc023d6771f6ce2b614eee5)).

Comment: Hey Mike! Is it normal that the Firebase file uploads to FIRStorage (using putData func) gets paused when the app is in the background? Meaning, if I go to the background the upload pauses, and when I come back (it doesn't matter how many hours later) the upload continues.

Comment: They should get killed--we don't currently do background uploads/downloads yet. It's technically a little more difficult (since the OS can kill it at any time), but also hard to expose in a clean way for resuming them and watching resume progress.